# Custom high score system not writing to ini properly

Tags: multidimensional-array, ini, game-maker-language

here's my full code for displaying a custom high score system:

```
// instance vars
var buffer = 0
var trigger = 0

// display setup
draw_set_font(fnt_highscores)
draw_set_color(c_white)
draw_set_halign(fa_left)
draw_set_valign(fa_middle)

// open save
ini_open("highscores.sav")

// reads file into 2d array
for (var i=0; i<10; i++)
{
    scores[0,i] = ini_read_string(string(i+1), "place", 0)
    scores[1,i] = ini_read_string(string(i+1), "name", 0)
    scores[2,i] = ini_read_string(string(i+1), "score", 0)
}

// cycles through array to look for new high score
for (var i=0; i<10; i++)
{
    // found one, run once.
    if (global.points >= int64(scores[2,i]) && trigger == 0)
    {   
        // starting from bottom, move value from number above to current
        for (var j=9; j>i; j--)
        {
            scores[0,j] = scores[0,j-1]
            scores[1,j] = scores[1,j-1]
            scores[2,j] = scores[2,j-1]
        }

        // new high score
        var initials = "beef"
        scores[0,i] = string(i+1)
        scores[1,i] = initials
        scores[2,i] = global.points     
        trigger++
    }

    // display score
    var j = i + 1
    draw_text(global.centerw - 150, global.centerh - 220 + buffer, string(j) + ".")
    draw_text(global.centerw - 100, global.centerh - 220 + buffer, scores[1,i])
    draw_text(global.centerw + 20, global.centerh - 220 + buffer, scores[2,i])
    buffer += 40    
}

// write to file - NOT WORKING!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
for (var i=0; i<10; i++)
{
    ini_write_string(string(i+1), "place", scores[0,i])
    ini_write_string(string(i+1), "name", scores[1,i])
    ini_write_string(string(i+1), "score", string(scores[2,i]))
}   

// close save
ini_close()

// draws flashing text
scr_flash_alpha(300)
draw_text(50,room_height - 50, "Start or R Key to Restart. Q to quit")
draw_set_alpha(1)
```

The "write to file" lines (near the buttom) is causing the issues.
Here's what it's doing when I beat a high score:

[image: High Score Broken]

Interestingly, if I comment out the write to ini lines, everything works perfectly as intended (just doesn't save the info to the ini, obviously)

[image: Working Fine Now!]

So, all my looping IS working, just when it goes to write to the ini it isn't writting the values correctly.
Any hints? I've been re-writing this for hours and getting no where *laughs*

Thank you so much in advance!!!

(EDIT: Here's my highscores.sav - note that entries 10 and 9 are exactly identical, down to the "place" value. Also interesting is that it starts at 10 and works it's way to 1. When I wrote the default saves, I numbered them 1-10.)

```
[10]
score="2500"
name="beef"
place="9"
[9]
score="2500"
name="beef"
place="9"
[8]
score="3000"
name="ASS"
place="8"
[7]
score="3800"
name="MAL"
place="7"
[6]
score="4600"
name="ADO"
place="6"
[5]
score="5500"
name="DSK"
place="5"
[4]
score="5500"
name="DIS"
place="4"
[3]
score="5900"
name="PPS"
place="3"
[2]
score="6100"
name="DSK"
place="2"
[1]
score="6800"
name="PSF"
place="1"
```

(side note: I know there's a few sloppy things in the code here and there, will be cleaning it all up once this is functioning.)

Answer (score 0):

rather simple and something I COMPLETELY overlooked. Simply needed to set `global.score = 0` after closing the ini.

logic behind this: in gamemaker language, a draw event occurs every frame. so it was opening the newly-created save file continuously and passed the high score check.